# jQuery Slider - Stops autoplaying when manually changing slide via paging navigation

Tags: jquery, tabs, slider, paging, autoplay

I've been trying to figure out for a while why my slider stops autoplaying when changing slides via the paging navigation.

I tried setting up a JSFiddle ( http://jsfiddle.net/9GuvL ) but it seems to not work at all there. So I have uploaded a preview for you: http://dperolio.rp-computers.co.uk/crusadegaming-help/

You can see it runs normally, unless you click one of the right slide tabs.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Consider provide a link to Slideshow documentation page

Comment: There is no documentation with it. What you see is what you get. And I use div inside of a, because as far as I know (as of HTML5) it is valid to use block elements (<div>) inside of <a> elements. It's possible I am mistaken though; I am a beginner coder, just doing the best I can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose this is the normal behavior, cause when user clicks on the tab she usually wants that tab be visible permanently.

there is a `pause()` call in the definition of `jump` method (in  the `slideshow.js`)

```
jump: function(index, control) {
    if ((Slideshow.lastSlide == index) || (Slideshow.slides.length <= 1)) return;
    Slideshow.pause();
    setTimeout(Slideshow.play, 5000)
```

You can comment it if you really want that

Comment: Thanks a bunch, that worked. :) However, if you click it right before it's about to switch or whatever, it will automatically switch right after you click one though, which isn't very good. Is there anyway I can pause it for a certain amount of time, easily? Like Slideshow.pause(5000);?

Comment: I don't understand you. Do you want to prevent switching to next tab if user already clicked on one, or you want to pause it for a certain amount of time? Those are different things, as it appears to me

Comment: I suppose you commented `.pause` call and now you want to return it but only for a certain period, right?

Comment: Pause it for a certain amount of time after the user clicks one of the slide tabs and the slide changes. The way it is now, you can click a tab right before it's about to change and the autoplay timer doesn't reset, so it will jump to the next slide (the one after the one you clicked). So I need it to either pause for a few seconds on that slide, or reset the timer.

Comment: try to set timeout `setTimeout(Slideshow.play, 5000)` right after the pause, which you shouldn't comment, let me know if that helps

Comment: do not comment pause in that case